# Ruby - Convert Hash with array values to array of hashes

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have this hash:

```
def aliases
  {
    blond: [
      'dark blond',
      'dirty blond',
      'honey blond',
      'sandy blond',
      'stawberry blond'
    ],
    brown: [
      'dark brown',
      'light brown'
    ],
    gray: [
      'grey'
    ]
  }
end
```

What is the most elegant way to convert it to:

```
[ { blond: 'dark blond' }, { blond: 'dirty blond' }, { brown: 'dark brown' } ... ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aliases.flat_map { |k,v| v.map { |s| { k=>s } } }
  #=> [{:blond=>"dark blond"}, {:blond=>"dirty blond"}, {:blond=>"honey blond"},
  #    {:blond=>"sandy blond"}, {:blond=>"stawberry blond"}, {:brown=>"dark brown"},
  #    {:brown=>"light brown"}, {:gray=>"grey"}]
```